# Chemstyle xkeyval error

Tags: errors, texlive, ubuntu, xkeyval, chemstyle

I recently installed texlive-science from the Ubuntu repos and received the following error when I compile:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `load-configurations' undefined in families `key'.
```

LaTeX works fine when `chemstyle` is not used. Any thoughts?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=4in]{anyfile.eps}
\end{center}
\caption {trial {\bf 1}.\label{s_scheme}}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

Abbreviated output:

```
) (./chemscheme.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
 (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
 (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/siunitx/config/si-abbr.cfg))
! Package xkeyval Error: `load-configurations' undefined in families `key'.
See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

Comment: Is there anything you're doing besides `\usepackage{chemstyle}`? If yes, please show that. The best would be a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Thats the  only mention of chemstyle in the preamble, here is the abbreviated output:


) (./chemscheme.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/siunitx/config/si-abbr.cfg))

! Package xkeyval Error: `load-configurations' undefined in families `key'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: Here is my MWE: $\documentclass{article}
$\usepackage{chemstyle}
$\begin{document}
$\begin{scheme}[H]
$ \begin{center}
$  \includegraphics[width=4in]{anyfile.eps}
$ \end{center}
$ \caption {trial {\bf 1}.
$ \label{s_scheme}}
$\end{scheme}
\end{document}

Comment: @plastictees: you may edit your question at any time in order to include code and additional information. I did it for you now.

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the result? I suspect you have a version mis-match somewhere between `chemstyle` and `siunitx`.

Comment: It seems that the Ubuntu people have managed to package mis-matched versions of `chemstyle` and `siunitx`. They've got v1 of `siunitx` but the updated `chemstyle` that needs version 2 of `siunitx`!

Answer (score 3):

In the minimal example, the `graphics` package is implicitly loaded. But the command

```
\includegraphics[width=4in]{anyfile.eps}
```

requires `graphicx` because of the `key=value` syntax in the optional argument. That's why the compilation must fail.

It's probably good to update to the most recent versions of `chemstyle` and `siunitx`. Ubuntu packages might be not up-to-date.

You may have a look at [How can I manually install a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows/2066#2066). Though the question was MiKTeX related, the answer contains general useful information and links to further resources.

Or filter our site by the tags [installing+packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing+packages).